# How to send post data with redirect from magento 2 for a payment gateway?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, redirect, post-data

we use `magento2/app/code/Paymentgateway/Example/Controller/Standard/Redirect.php`

```
public function execute()
{
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    if ($order->getBillingAddress())
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(
            $this->getExampleModel()->buildExampleRequest($order)
        );
    }
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Create **a custom hidden from this submit and using window.load** function submit form.

- **Create  a form  with required fields and value to payment gateway.**
- **Make all fields as hidden type**
- **Then make this form  action url to your pg**
- **And using window.load submit this form**

Comment: not success yet please provide an example

Comment: any success!? if yes please post here

Answer (score 0):

Create a from in your template file with submit URL and also create a block function that return all data that you need to submit.

Here is the sample code for the same.

```
<form action="Submit-URL-HERE" method="POST" name="fromPay">
    <?php foreach ($this->getDataToSubmit() as $name => $value): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    document.forms['fromPay'].submit();
    -->
</script>
```